# ExpandableListView item clicks

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, android-menu, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to use an ExpandableListView in the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I cannot get my OnItemClickListeners to respond to item clicks. I have attached the SlidingMenu to the Activity through the following:

```
slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
slidingMenu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
slidingMenu.setBehindWidth(getSlidingMenuWidth());
slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slideoutmenu);
```

The ExpandableListView is in the view inflated from R.layout.slideoutmenu, and I am setting the click listeners as below:   `((ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu_explist)).setOnItemClickListener(this);`
The event listeners are never fired when I click on items. How does one handle click events in the views of a SlidingMenu?

Comment: Does clicks works if you put ExpandableList outside of Sliding menu?

Comment: No, it is not working. Thank-you for this idea.

Answer (score 0):

write the click event in expandedlistview adapter .where you are defining the content. now use framelayout to replace the content of  view